# Rails renders erb file in preference of haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I used a generator to make the file `index.html.erb`.

Then I thought, wait, I want `haml`. So I installed `haml` and `haml-rails` and added `index.html.haml` to the same folder. Rails rendered the original view.

When I deleted the erb view, and left haml one, Rails said it cannot find order's index page.

So why isn't my rails app rendering the haml file?

Comment: And remove the .erb files... I don't know what's checked (and rendered) first, could be .erb.

Comment: Server restart worked, thanks sts for the sort-of suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Server restart fixed this problem.